# process.start() method after a certain video

Tags: c#, process.start

I'm trying to launch a program that I've already developed after a specific video. But the weather forecast program begins first and the videos start to play. What should I do?

this is the code:

```
foreach (string fileName in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
     if (fileName!="C:\\Users\\bahri.eker\\Desktop\\FINAL\\hava.wmv")
     {
         axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.playItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia);
     }
     else
     {
         Process.Start("C:/Users/bahri.eker/Desktop/FINAL/weatherForeCast.exe").WaitForExit();
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }

     axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.next();
}
```